# Dropdowns not doing anything when I click on them

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have problem with dropdown items. When I click on them, they don't work.

Here's my code:

```
val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options\[0\]) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    }
                ){
                    Text(text = selectionOption) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

how to deal with it

Comment: _Specifically,_ what does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].